# Incorrect behavior of TimeObject in version 13

Tags: date-and-time, version-13

I used to use `TimeObject` in my code and pass it the string coming from a database system as follows and it used to convert it to the correct time.

```
TimeObject["3:28 PM","Minute"]
```

> TimeObject[{15, 28}, "Minute"]

But now after updating to version 13. I get:

```
TimeObject["3:28 PM","Minute"]
```

> TimeObject[{3, 28}, "Minute"]

What in the world is this? Is there a way to get the old functionality back? All my code is now messed up.

---

More screwups:

```
oldMonthFormat=AssociationThread[DateRange[DatePlus[CurrentDate["Month"],{-15,"Month"}],CurrentDate["Month"]]->RandomInteger[{0,100},16]];
newMonthFormat=AssociationThread[DateRange[DateObject[{2020,9}],DateObject[{2021,12}]]->RandomInteger[{0,100},16]];
```

Now let's try merging the totals by month:

```
Merge[{oldMonthFormat,newMonthFormat},Total]
```

doesn't `Merge` the months anymore. Everything about `DateObject` and `TimeObject` is screwed. This used to work in `version 12.3.1`.

What the hell did they do to Date and Time functions in `version 13`? Very disappointed with what I am seeing now.

- Old Format: `DateObject[{2021, 12}, "Month", "Gregorian", -5.]`
- New Format: `DateObject[{2021, 12}, "Month"]`

Comment: In v13: The `FullForm` of `DateObject` at certain granularities no longer explicitly includes default values for the calendar or time zone. [Incompatible Changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html)

Comment: @BenIzd then why some functions are doing it and others are not? I am happy to make changes in my code but why is for example `CurrentDate` still on the older format then?

Comment: @user13892 I'm also looking for an answer. Also for the first problem you can use this: `TimeObject@
 FromDateString["3:28 PM", {"Hour", ":", "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}, 
  TimeZone -> 0]`

Answer (score 7):

If you experiment a bit, you'll find that it's just ignoring everything including and after the space. I have no idea if that's intended, but the behaviour you relied on does not appear to be documented.

The following works, if nothing else:

```
SemanticImportString["3:28pm", "Time"][[1]]
```

Comment: You could also add `TextString@SemanticImportString["3:28pm", "Time"][[1]]` to make it display `15:28`